# Getting the Activity inside Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am trying to access the activity on which my Imageview is, so I can use the URL of an Image of type SVG and display it to the user using the GlideToVectorYou library.

```
GlideToVectorYou.justLoadImage(activity, IMAGE_URI, targetImageView)
```

But when I try to get access to the activity using R.layout.**activityname**, a syntax error appears.
this is the code that I'm using

```
 Uri myurl = Uri.parse(match.getFlag());
 GlideToVectorYou.justLoadImage(R.layout.item_basketball, myurl, iv_location);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.layout.item_basketball` is just an integer ID for your activity layout - not the activity instance itself. If you want the activity in your adapter you would need to pass it in when you construct the adapter and save it as a class member (example below), or check if your adapter base class already can provide it via `getActivity()` or `getContext()` or a similar method.

```
class MyAdapter(private val activity: Activity) : BaseAdapter() {
    fun someMethod() {
        // then you can access "activity" in your adapter methods
        GlideToVectorYou.justLoadImage(activity, IMAGE_URI, targetImageView)
    }
}
```

and when you create it in your Activity, you would just do something like this

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(this)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was good, but I found out that the Glide library could handle the.SVG images too. The answer would be differently helpful for dealing with adapters.

Comment: Yeah, but I figure out after reading some documentation that the Glide library could handle these types of images, so I won't need to use the GlideToVector library to handle SVG images, therefore, no need to get the activity from the adapter.

Comment: Makes sense, glad it's working for you

Answer (score 0):

You need a activity reference. R.layout.somethinghere is the layout reference.

On your adapter constructor add a activity parameter and use it inside the adapter.

If you call adapter constructor from an activity, just pass "this" as parameter. If call from a fragment, use "requireActivity" (if using kotlin) or analogous method (getActivity, for example) if using Java